# Wildfly Container Not Reachable from Host

Tags: java, docker, maven, jboss, wildfly

I need to access the application deployed to wildfly inside of a container, but I'm unable to do so. I'm absolutely sure the application is running on port 8443 inside of the container.
To build the image, I use this command, note the port forwarding argument.

```
docker run -p 8443:8443 folio-authentication-local:latest
```

To run the image I use this command:

```
docker run -p 8443:8443 folio-authentication-local:latest
```

No errors when the container starts up. Also, I can open a shell into the container and hit the endpoint and I see the content returned (see screenshot below).

However from the host browser, I get an error that the page can't found (see the second screenshot).

Hopefully, someone can let me know what I am missing.

Dockerfile:

```
### BUILD image
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine as builder
ARG BRANCH_NAME=local
ARG mongo_replicaset=localhost:27017,localhost:27017,localhost:27017

EXPOSE 8443

# Create app folder for sources
RUN mkdir -p /build
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml /build

# Download all required dependencies into one layer
RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins

# Copy source code
COPY src /build/src

# Build application
RUN mvn package

WORKDIR /
# Copy all configurations into the image from the host
RUN mkdir -p /WildflyConfiguration
COPY  /WildflyConfiguration/* /WildflyConfiguration

# Copy all scripts into the image from the host
RUN mkdir -p /SetStandaloneXmlSettingsScripts
COPY  /SetStandaloneXmlSettingsScripts/* /SetStandaloneXmlSettingsScripts

# Set permissions on the folder
RUN chmod -R 777 ./SetStandaloneXmlSettingsScripts

#Update the standalone.xml file
RUN if [ "${BRANCH_NAME}" = "development" ]; then \ 
    ./SetStandaloneXmlSettingsScripts/setEKSDevStandaloneXmlSettings.sh; \
elif [ "${BRANCH_NAME}" = "local" ]; then \
    ./SetStandaloneXmlSettingsScripts/setLocalStandaloneXmlSettings.sh; \       
else \
    echo "There was no branch name found that matches your standalon" && exit 1; \
fi 

#Create the deployment
FROM jboss/wildfly:21.0.2.Final as Final

#Copy the artifact to the deployments folder
COPY --from=builder /build/target/Authentication.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/Authentication.war

#Copy the standalone configuration into wildfly
COPY --from=builder /WildflyConfiguration/standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh"]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, WildFly is configured to bind to the loopback address (127.0.0.1), hence why you cannot access the server from outside of the container. You can override this by passing the `-b` argument to `standalone.sh`.

For example, to bind to all available interfaces, you could modify your `ENTRYPOINT` to the following.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```